# If a, b, c are positive real numbers such that $a^2+ b^2+ c^2 = 1$ $( \frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{c}) +a +b +c \geq 4\sqrt{3}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If a, b, c are positive real numbers such that $a^2+ b^2+ c^2 = 1$
>
> Show that:
> $$\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{c}+a +b +c \geq 4\sqrt{3}.$$

**My attempt:**

First , I used Holder's : $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\geq \frac{27}{3(a+b+c)}$$

similarly:

$$ a+b+c \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)} = \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3}$$

Which gives us:

$$LHS \geq \frac{27}{3(a+b+c)}+ \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3}$$

By AM-GM:

$$LHS \geq 2\sqrt{3} \times (a+b+c)$$

So all we need to do is prove that $$2\sqrt{3} \times (a+b+c)\geq 4\sqrt{3}$$

And  this means we need to prove $$a+b+c \geq 2 $$

Which I can't.

I am not looking for a solution , only  hints that would  guide me through solving it .

Thanks in advance for any communicated help !

Comment: Do you want to prove $$a^2+b^2+c^2=1\implies a+b+c\geq 2?$$ Because this is obviously false: see $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)$. Or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: Would the downvote care to explain why the downvote? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative approach using the *point of incidence technique*.

We will first employ the AM-GM inequality, followed by QM-AM:
\begin{align*}
a+b+c+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c&=a+b+c+\frac13\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right) + \frac23\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)\\
&\geqslant \frac{6}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt[6]{abc\cdot\frac1{abc}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}\\
&\geqslant 2\sqrt{3}+\frac2{\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}3}}\\
&= 2\sqrt{3}+\frac2{\sqrt{\frac13}}=4\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}

Equality holds iff $a=b=c=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$.

---

*Observation.* This problem is a stronger version of an inequality that [appeared in Macedonia's National Olympiad back in $1999$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1068820h2006038p14040781). Notwithstanding, a similar idea to that of Macedonia yields a solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you pls expain thouroughly what the point of incidence technique  means  ? I've read a post  from mathstacks but can't grasp the concept well , any references would be of great help !=.Thanks!

Comment: @AdamBoussif : Basically, you study equality cases, which have to be preserved along the whole process. In this case, equality holds iff $a=b=c=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\implies \frac1a=\frac1b=\frac1c=\sqrt{3}$. If we want to use AM-GM, we have to be careful, since equality holds here iff all the summands have the same value. Thus, it would make no sense to employ AM-GM with $a+\frac1a$ since $\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\neq \sqrt{3}$ (hence, we would loose the equality case). However, if we instead consider $a+\frac1{3a}$, the equality case would still be there as $\frac1{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}3$.

Comment: i see ,  clever technique that I should keep in mind , Thank you  for the instant answer , i understand it better now  , Thank you again ! and have a nice day !

Comment: The typical "beginner" mistake in such problems is to claim that the maximum value should rather be $6$, since in virtue of AM-GM: $a+b+c+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\geqslant 6$, but the equality case is no attained, since it would require $a=b=c=1$, which, then again, does not fulfill $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

Comment: @AdamBoussif I am glad it helped!! It's a nice method to keep in mind :D

Comment: @AdamBoussif If you are interested in seeing many, many uses of the *point of incidence technique*, have a look at the first chapter of [this book](https://www.numberwonder.co.uk/ArnoldHagger/Diamonds.pdf) by Tran Phuong :)

Answer (score 1):

By your argument, we already have
$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c+a+b+c\geq\frac9{a+b+c}+\frac{(a+b+c)^3}3=\frac9u+\frac{u^3}3\equiv f(u)$$
where $u=a+b+c>0$. Try to show that $f'(x)=0$ only has one root $x^*=\sqrt3$ when $x>0$ and $f''(x^*)>0$, therefore $f(u)\geq\min_{x>0}f(x)=f(x^*)=4\sqrt3$.

Comment: You may use AM-GM to get  $\frac{3}{u} + \frac{3}{u} + \frac{3}{u} + \frac{u^3}{3} \ge 4\sqrt[4]{9} = 4\sqrt 3$. (You may use calculus to motivate your solution. Then in your solution, you use AM-GM/C-S etc without calculus.)